# Problem with selecting a radio button via Robot Framework

Tags: radio-button, robotframework

I can't find out the command syntax for selecting a `radio` button.
For example the button: NL

I have searched on the internet but I could not find a good example.
I hope that you can help me. I'm new at this so I really need some help.

This is the piece of HTML:

```
    <tr>
        <th class="category">
            <span class="required">*</span>         custom_Schermtaal       </th>
        <td>
            <label for="custom_field_1_value_0"><input class="ace" id="custom_field_1_value_0" tabindex="5" type="radio" name="custom_field_1" value="NL" required  />
<span class="lbl">&#160;NL</span>
</label>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the only option but I find xpath to be the easiest way around in robot framework.

In order to click the input you are looking for you can use xpath. In the documentation the method like Get Element take an input parameter that is the locator. There is a whole section on locator in the documentation. You can use jquery, text, xpath...

Xpath is a way of selecting something in the html document. Use double slash (//) to say you are looking everywhere in the document. Then you select the parent (here, TR) then you can describe the path to the element you are looking for

```
Click Element    xpath://tr/td/label/input
```

Try reading those pages :

Xpath : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath

Selenium2Library _ section locator : http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Locating%20elements

Answer (score 2):

I presume element id and name is not dynamic.To click on radio button.

1. use Wait Until Element Is Visible.
2. Then click on the element.

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible   xpath://td//label[@for='custom_field_1_value_0']//input[@name='custom_field_1'][@type='radio']      10

Click Element    xpath://td//label[@for='custom_field_1_value_0']//input[@name='custom_field_1'][@type='radio']
```

OR if you like the take the reference of `custom_Schermtaal` try below code.

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible   xpath://th[contains(.,'custom_Schermtaal')]/following::td[1]//input      10

Click Element    xpath://th[contains(.,'custom_Schermtaal')]/following::td[1]//input
```

Hope this helps.